# Twitter4j.Getting users from country

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j, but I have not found a solution to the API.
I need to get a list of users with specified country.

How can I do that?

Comment: I see you are new here I suggest you look at [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As of Twitter4J version 4.0.x there is **no** known method to query Twitter users via a given `country` parameter (on a global scale).

For reference, see the current Twitter4J API documentation, [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/SearchResource.html#search-twitter4j.Query-) and [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#setGeoCode-twitter4j.GeoLocation-double-twitter4j.Query.Unit-):